# unexpected end of file in

Tags: php, html

I am trying to insert something in a database, but when i use the script, it gives the end of script error.

Whatever order i put in, it never fixes it.

The code:

```
<?PHP
include('inc/database/db_connect.php'); //includes db settings  

function sernum()
{
    $template = 'X9XX-XX99-99XX-99X9-XXXX';
    $k = strlen($template);
    $sernum = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$k; $i++) {
        switch($template[$i]) {
            case 'X': $sernum .= chr(rand(65, 90)); break;
            case '9': $sernum .= rand(0,9); break;
            case '-': $sernum .= '-'; break;
    }
    return $sernum;
        mysqli_query($db_connect,"INSERT INTO AlphaKeys (`AlphaKey`) VALUES ('$sernum');
        mysqli_close($db_connect);
       }
     }
}
echo '<prev>';

for ($i=0; $i < 20; $i++) echo sernum(), '<br/>';

echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

and db_connect.php

```
<?PHP
$connect_error = "Sorry, we're experiencing downtime, please try again.";
$db_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","********","B&5I)0U%a-B}","********") or die($connect_error);
?>
```

I'm trying to figure out and i can't...

Comment: Watch your brackets. Delete one of the three curly brackets before "echo 'prev';"

Answer (score 0):

Correct this line

```
mysqli_query($db_connect,"INSERT INTO AlphaKeys (`AlphaKey`) VALUES ('$sernum');
```

to

```
mysqli_query($db_connect,"INSERT INTO AlphaKeys (`AlphaKey`) VALUES ('$sernum')");
```

Comment: ah also the switch is not closed

Comment: also your function is returning $sernum; and then the query is getting executed ?